# Visual Studio Code でマークダウンのプレビューを表示する方法

Tags: vscode, markdown

以前から私は Visual Studio Code でマークダウンの編集，プレビューを行っていたのですが，ある日今まで右上に表示されていたプレビューを開くアイコンが消えているのに気づきました．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また，コマンドパレットから markdown と検索しても以下の写真のように何も表示されませんでした．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Visual Studio Code のバージョンは1.52.0，OS は Windows10 です．

どなたか解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 私の環境で試してみたところ、Windows 10 の VSCode 1.51.0 (October 2020) ではプレビューのボタンがあったので、1.52.0 (November 2020) まででの挙動変更かバグかもしれません。似たような issue が最近立っているのを見つけましたが、まだ進展はありませんでした: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112058

Comment: 原因の切り分けのため、一度[全ての拡張機能を無効にして](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues#run-with-extensions-disabled)起動しても同じようにプレビューボタンが表示されなくなるか試してみていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん  
ご返信ありがとうございます．    
拡張機能をすべて無効にして再起動してみましたが，変化はありませんでした．  
情報ありがとうございます．  
気長に修正を待ってみます．